# Использование юзера после авторизации ASP.NET Core MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

В процессе написание дипломной работы столкнулся с проблемой. После аутентификации и авторизации получаю доступ к сайту, но не могу понять как использовать информацию юзера дальше по коду без костылей и вечных запросов к бд. Есть ли способ хранить где-то юзера и делать запрос на получение информации о нем?

Comment: Вам нужно использовать какой-то токен который получил юзер после авторизации? Не совсем понятно "информция юзера". Если вам нужно какой-то токен туда-сюда по сайту мотать, то можете просто куки использовать

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0